# matching by URL parameters in Rails routes

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-5, url-routing

How to match route with specific url parameters in it?

For example, I need to redirect page with param `page=1` to page without params:

```
#need /categories?page=1 --> /categories
```

**routes.rb**

```
match '/*?page=1*' => redirect { |params, request| request.path }, via: [:get, :post]
```

But it doesn't work. It cannot match pattern with `?` delimeter.

Is it real?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking of route globbing/wildcard segments, which are valid syntax: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

In which case you probably want:
`match '/*page' => redirect { |params, request| request.path }, via: [:get, :post]`

Another approach might be to add the following to your controller action instead of your routes file.

For example, in `categories_controller.rb`

```
def index
  if params[:page].present?
    redirect_to categories_path
  end
  # ...the rest of your index action here
end
```

Comment: Ookay. I know this solution, but I just want to know if it is real through routes. I have a lot of controllers and it is not responsive solution to add redirection to all controllers